# Unique combinations of two lists – comparison at each index position

Tags: python

I've searched pretty thoroughly, and haven't found any info –  hopefully I didn't miss anything.  I have two lists:

```
list1 = (a, b, c, d)
list2 = (a, b*, c*, d)
```

I would like to generate all possible unique 2 list pairings that only look for differences at each index value.  For example, the results here would be:

```
list1_new = (a, b*, c, d)
list2_new = (a, b, c*, d)
```

Note:  I don't care to distinguish between `list1` and `list2`, i.e., `list1_new = (a, b*, c*, d)` would not be considered unique as it matches the original `list2`.

I've played around with `itertools` but haven't been able to figure out how to compare at each index position.

I used small lists for this example, but I actually will have larger lists of 10+ items.

Comment: Do you mean lists? Because AFAIR sets usually are unordered and they don't have indices.

Comment: Ooops, I suppose I do - thanks!  I had been using sets (to avoid any duplicate entries), but clearly for this comparison order matters, so I can switch to lists.  Let me update the question...

Comment: One way is that you can form a list of indices for which the sets elements are different. In your case [1,2]. Then use itertools.combinations on this list that would denote the indices where the elements exchange happen. You will then have to remove duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ["a ", "b ", "c ", "d ", "e ", "f ", "g "]
list2 = ["a ", "b*", "c*", "d ", "e*", "f*", "g "]

# figure out which offsets have alternable values
crosses = [a != b for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
offsets = [i for i,cross in enumerate(crosses) if cross]

# decide which offsets will be swapped
basis = [[0,1] for ofs in offsets]
basis[0] = [0]       # only the first half - remainder are mirrors
swaps = product(*basis)
next(swaps, None)    # skip base state == (list1, list2)

# print all viable swaps
list3 = list1[:]
list4 = list2[:]
for sw in swaps:
    # build output lists
    for which,offs in zip(sw, offsets):
        list3[offs] = [list1, list2][which][offs]
        list4[offs] = [list2, list1][which][offs]
    # display output
    print("\n{}\n{}".format(list3, list4))
```

gives

```
['a ', 'b ', 'c ', 'd ', 'e ', 'f*', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c*', 'd ', 'e*', 'f ', 'g ']

['a ', 'b ', 'c ', 'd ', 'e*', 'f ', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c*', 'd ', 'e ', 'f*', 'g ']

['a ', 'b ', 'c ', 'd ', 'e*', 'f*', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c*', 'd ', 'e ', 'f ', 'g ']

['a ', 'b ', 'c*', 'd ', 'e ', 'f ', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c ', 'd ', 'e*', 'f*', 'g ']

['a ', 'b ', 'c*', 'd ', 'e ', 'f*', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c ', 'd ', 'e*', 'f ', 'g ']

['a ', 'b ', 'c*', 'd ', 'e*', 'f ', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c ', 'd ', 'e ', 'f*', 'g ']

['a ', 'b ', 'c*', 'd ', 'e*', 'f*', 'g ']
['a ', 'b*', 'c ', 'd ', 'e ', 'f ', 'g ']
```

Comment: Sorry, commented before your edit.  I think this is perfect!  Very cool, thanks!